# How to not display a plot drawn by a function and obtain only invisible object?

Tags: r, plot

If a function draws a graph inside the function using `plot` and also returns an invisible object, how do I only keep the object and not display the plot?

```
some_func <- function() {
  plot(1:10)
  return(invisible(10))
}

my_value <- some_func() # R/Rstudio draws a plot! don't want that
```

Comment: On Nix machines this should work: `graphics.off()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are doing this, presumably you wish to call `plot` only for some side effect. Usually this would be the case if you are interested in getting a return value from the plot function, for example using `boxplot` to calculate the statistics.

With some plot methods, there is an argument `plot = FALSE` you can use. for example with boxplots you can specify `boxplot(..., plot = FALSE)`.

But this does not work with the basic plot function.  Other options are to use a different plotting library, such as lattice or ggplot, that allow you to assign a plot to an object, rather than draw it. But if you really need to do this with base plot, then the only way I can think of is to send the output to a device other than your screen. For example, to send the output to a temporary .png file and then delete the file, you can do

```
some_func <- function() {
  png("temp.xyz")
  a=plot(1:10, )
  dev.off()
  file.remove("temp.xyz")
  return(invisible(10))
}

my_value <- some_func()
```